# Wkhtmltopdf giving error log with exit return Code

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

True Html to PDF conversion of '-' failed. Wkhtmltopdf output:
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
QNetworkAccessFileBackendFactory: URL has no schema set, use file:// for files
[===========>                                                ] 19%
[==============>                                             ] 24%
[===================>                                        ] 33%
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
[============================================================] 100%
QPainter::begin(): Returned false
Error: Unable to write to destination
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.

I am trying to create pdf using wkhtmltopdf previously it worked. but suddenly it is getting above log and file does not generate in the shared location

i checked the access permission and all relevant details but no change of these

Answer (score 0):

FYI : Issue found and rectified. Wkhtmltopdf can not create sub directories and we have to manual create it before create the file